# Getting two wp_link_pages output

Tags: loop, wp-link-pages

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yr35p.jpg

As you can see in the picture above. I got two links for each page.
I'm using `<div class="pagelink"><?php wp_link_pages('pagelink=Source %'); ?></div>`
for the top one and the bottom one is automatically appearing because of `<!--nextpage-->`

So how do I remove the links in the bottom. If I remove `<!--nextpage-->` the top one will dissapear as well.

Thanks.

Edit: My single.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="content_box">

        <div id="left_box">

            <div id="content">

                <div id="content_inner">
<?php 
                if (have_posts()) : 
                    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                    <p class="post_author"><em>by</em> <?php the_author(); ?></p>
<div class="pagelink"><?php wp_link_pages('pagelink=Source %'); ?></div>
                    <div class="format_text">
<?php the_content('<p>Read the rest of this entry &raquo;</p>'); ?>
<?php link_pages('<p><strong>Pages:</strong> ', '</p>', 'number'); ?>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <?php comments_template(); ?>
<?php 
                    endwhile;
                else: ?>

                    <h1>Uh oh.</h1>
                    <div class="format_text">
                        <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria. Wanna search instead?</p>
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/searchform.php'); ?>
                    </div>

                </div>
<?php 
                endif; ?>

            </div>

            <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/left_bar.php')?>

        </div>

        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

My theme is: Neoclassical

Comment: Do you use your PHP code in manually in posts, or you edited single.php file?

Comment: @Mamaduka I put this in `<div class="pagelink"><?php wp_link_pages('pagelink=Source %'); ?></div>` in my single.php

Comment: can you paste your single.php code or tell what theme you're using?

Comment: @Mamaduka Added in first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your theme is using old and deprecated function `link_pages` to display page-links for paginated posts.

Just replace this chunk of code:

```
<div class="pagelink"><?php wp_link_pages('pagelink=Source %'); ?></div>
                    <div class="format_text">
<?php the_content('<p>Read the rest of this entry &raquo;</p>'); ?>
<?php link_pages('<p><strong>Pages:</strong> ', '</p>', 'number'); ?>
                    </div>
```

with this:

```
                    <div class="format_text">
<?php the_content('<p>Read the rest of this entry &raquo;</p>'); ?>
<?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">Pages:', 'after' => '</div>', 'pagelink' => 'Source %' ) ); ?>
                    </div>
```

Comment: I commented `link_pages` and it works as I wanted it to. What does you code do? Should I change it to yours? And thanks a lot! btw, checked out your homepage, very similar to my name :P

Comment: Remove `link_pages` you don't need that old deprecated function anymore, my code shows how you should use `wp_link_pages`. yes it similar but meaning is different

Comment: I see, Thank you. Now I can move on and finish my site :) And I see that you put my div inside the fuction, pretty smart!