# wp_link_pages output appears twice

Tags: filters, wp-link-pages

I believe this is completely different than the question asked [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26540/getting-two-wp-link-pages-output).

I'm adding pagination to my theme using a filter hook. The output appears at the beginning and end of my content, rather than just the end.

My function, in the template's functions.php file:

```
add_filter('the_content','pagination_after_post',1);
/**
 * Adds pagination after the post
 *
 * @uses is_single()
 */

function pagination_after_post($content){
    if( is_single() ){
        $content .= '<div class="pagination">' . wp_link_pages('before=&after=&next_or_number=next&nextpagelink=Next&previouspagelink=Previous') . '</div>';
        return $content;
    } // if
} // pagination_after_post
```

Here is my single.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

        <div id="centercol">

        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>



                <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

                    <h2 class="singleh2"><a title="<?php _e('Permanent Link to',woothemes); ?> <?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <div class="date-comments">
                        <p class="fl"><?php the_time('l, M j, Y \a\t g:i a'); ?> by <a href="<?= get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ?>" rel="author"><?= get_the_author() ?></a></p>
                        <p class="fr"><?php the_category(', ') ?></p>                                                 
                    </div>        

                    <div class="entry">
                        <?php echo woo_get_embed('embed','500','360','video-post'); ?>
                        <?php the_content(__('<span class="continue">Continue Reading</span>',woothemes)); ?>                       
                    </div>

                    <?php the_tags('<p>Tags: ', ', ', '</p>'); ?> 

                </div><!--/post-->          

                <div id="comments">
                    <?php comments_template(); ?>
                </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <div class="navigation">
            <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_post_link(); ?></div>
            <div class="alignright"><?php next_post_link(); ?> </div>
        </div>      

    <?php endif; ?>                         

        </div><!--/centercol-->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And a screenshot of the issue:

[image]

Comment: in your functions.php did you added action hook?

Comment: oops you need to add add_filter

Comment: @ntechi I've got `add_filter('the_content','pagination_after_post',1);` on the first line. Anything more than that?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set the 'echo' parameter of [`wp_link_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages) to 'echo=0';
example:

```
$content .= '<div class="pagination">' . wp_link_pages('before=&after=&next_or_number=next&nextpagelink=Next&previouspagelink=Previous&echo=0') . '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this

```
add_filter ('the_content', 'pagination_after_post',1);
function pagination_after_post($content) {
   if(is_single()) {
      $content.= '<div class="pagination">' . wp_link_pages('before=&after=&next_or_number=next&nextpagelink=Next&previouspagelink=Previous') . '</div>';

   }
   return $content;
}
```

Comment: How is this different from what I posted, besides the lack of a comment between the add_filter and the function?

Comment: Oh, the return is outside the if. Trying now.

Comment: Moved the return outside the if single. The issue persists. It's not that I have 0 returned results, it's that I have two, one before and one after the content. It feels like it's doing `"pagination" . $content . "pagination"`.